# UIImagePickerController - avoiding the "Preview" screen

Tags: iphone, uiimagepickercontroller

When I use the UIImagePickerController to take a picture, after taking the picture it always takes me to a Preview screen where it says "Retake" or "Use". Is there any way to avoid going to this screen? Even when I use a custom overlay screen, and I set the picker.allowsEditing to FALSE, it still takes me to this screen. I've seen other apps which avoid going to the preview screen, so how would I do it?

This is the code I'm using:

```
FrontOverlayView *overlay = [[FrontOverlayView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,460)];
UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
picker.delegate = self;
picker.allowsEditing = NO;
picker.cameraOverlayView = overlay;
[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
[picker release];
[overlay release];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
picker.showsCameraControls = NO;
```

should do it.

Comment: it removes the camera capture button also